# SharePoint Publishing BlobCache error with SetResponseHeaders

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my error logs I see the following error and stacktrace:

Page error: **URL:** /SiteCollectionImages/Push/zh-cn/Machining_calculators.jpg
**Debugging enabled:** False
**Correlation ID:** 857a397e-8063-447c-af92-b114074282b8
**Message**: 
Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
**Source**: System.Web
**StackTrace**:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String name, String value)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.SetResponseHeaders(HttpContext context, BlobCacheEntry target)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.SendCachedFile(HttpContext context, BlobCacheEntry target, 
   SPUserToken currentUserToken, SiteEntry currentSiteEntry)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.SendCachedFile(HttpContext context, BlobCacheEntry target, SiteEntry currentSiteEntry)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.HandleCachedFile(HttpContext context, BlobCacheEntry target, Boolean anonymousUser, SiteEntry currentSiteEntry) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.BlobCache.RewriteUrl(Object sender, EventArgs e, Boolean preAuthenticate)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingHttpModule.AuthorizeRequestHandler(Object sender, EventArgs ea)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

It seems that the inbuilt BlobCache attempts to set httpresponse-headers after response has been sent to server. Does anyone know how to correct this, or is it a bug in the SharePoint-platform?

Update: My web.config looks like this:

```
<BlobCache location="d:\BlobCache\companyname" path="\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|jfif|bmp|dib|tif|tiff|ico|png|wdp|hdp|css|js|asf|avi|flv|m4v|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|rm|rmvb|wma|wmv)$" maxSize="10" enabled="true" />
```

And it is also worth mentioning that this doesn't happen for all image-requests. Approximately 90-95% of all image request end up being propertly cached in the specified location and sent to the client with proper response codes.

Update2:
Hooks into HttpApplication from HttpModules:

```
app.PreSendRequestContent += new EventHandler(app_PreSendRequestContent);
```

and some SharePoint specific code in HttpModule:

```
var spApp = context as SPHttpApplication;
if (spApp != null)
{
    var labelHandler = new VaryByLabelHandler();
    spApp.RegisterGetVaryByCustomStringHandler(labelHandler);
    var countryHandler = new VaryByCountryHandler();
    spApp.RegisterGetVaryByCustomStringHandler(countryHandler);
    var claimHandler = new VaryByClaimHandler();
    spApp.RegisterGetVaryByCustomStringHandler(claimHandler);
}
```

Comment: These types of problems are really hard to diagnose without knowing more about the environment. What custom code is running in this farm?

Comment: Well, lots and lots actually, but what might be relevant in this case is a few custom http-modules, (handling custom 404 etc.).
What confuses me is that there is no trace of them in the stacktrace, and I can really find anything in my custom handlers that causes this. Unable to reproduce in my local dev-machine as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by what I see as a bug in the SharePoint-platform. The issue affected images stored in SiteCollection-library, but not all images. After digging deeper, and with some luch. I could see that these images had been uploaded before we turned off content approval on the list, as could be seen by using the "Manage Content & Structure"-tool. These images were still in Draft-mode. This should not be so since we turned off content approval, but for some reason this setting affected the BlobCache's ability to propertly serve them.

Exactly which images were affected could easily be observed by using Fiddler, and seeing that these images prompted a 304-response from server, whilst other were being fetched directly from client cache.

The solution was to perform a mass-checkout and mass-checkin of these images, and then they got Approval-state "Approved", and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a customer http handler that would bypass / overwrite native SharePoint ones ? Looks like something manage to send back the response before SharePoint retrieve it from the disk or fetch it from the database and store it afterward on the disk.

Can you give us your blobcache entry on the web config ? Is the target location for the blob storage being filled upon request ? Did you put relevant permission on that folder ?

Kindly.

Comment: Thank you for you interest. I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: are the images that are not going in the blob cache stored within a document library ? (*not* an asset library or style library for example)

Comment: They are all mostly stored in SiteCollectionImages. But I can see no pattern as to which image gets stored correctly and which not.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this isn't actually caused by the blob cache, but one of the http modules. Do you for example hook HttpApplication.ReleaseRequestState anywhere? In which case that needs to be changed to HttpApplication.EndRequest. That's a quite common reason for this problem...

Comment: I've updated the question with our hooks into the HttpApplication-object.